# Maximum from a list with data filter

Tags: haskell

so i have a data GoodBad where i give Good or Bad and an Int

```
    data GoodBad = Good Int |Bad Int
```

And i have a list full of GoodBad and i am trying to get the maximum of the Ints that has the Good pair

Here's an example for easier understanding

```
maxGoodBad = [Good 2] --> 2

maxGoodBad [Good  2, Good  3, Bad  3] --> 3
```

If there's no Good in the list it should give back error

Here's how i tried:

```
    maxGoodBad :: [GoodBad] -> Int
    maxGoodBad (x:xs)
     | length (filter (Good n) (x:xs)) < 1 = error "ERROR"
     | otherwise = maximum (filter (Good n) (x:xs))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first filter out the `Good` elements, you can for example use list comprehension for that:

```
[ v | Good v <- xs ]
```

with `xs` a list of `GoodBad`s. Here we produce a list of `Int`s, since we unwrap `v` out of the `Good` data constructor. Next we can call `maximum` on the list of values, so:

```
maxGoodBad :: [GoodBad] -> Int
maxGoodBad xs = maximum [v | Good v <- xs]
```

It is *not* a good idea to work with `length`: length takes linear time on a list, and for infinite lists, it will get stuck in an infinite loop. If you want to check if the list is empty, you can make use of [**`null :: [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null):

```
maxGoodBad :: [GoodBad] -> Int
maxGoodBad xs
    | null vs = error "empty"
    | otherwise = maximum vs
    where vs = [ v | Good v <- xs ]
```

But checking if the list is empty is *not* necessary, since `maximum` will already error for an empty list.